# How to know the different types of alelles for each SNP in a .ped file

Tags: r

I have a .ped file where I have in each column differents alelles for each SNP.

Flori JG05001 0 0 0 -9 T C A A T C C T T T C T G G A A G G C C C C G G G G A

Flori JG05002 0 0 0 -9 C C A A C C T T T T C T G G G A G A T C A C G G G G A

Flori JG05002 0 0 0 -9 C C A A C C T C T T C T G G G A G A T C A C G G G G A

Flori JG05002 0 0 0 -9 C C A A C C T C T T C T G G G A G A T C A C G G G G T

what I want is to know for each column the different types of alelles posibles, i.e. for column 7 I will have only the T and C possibilites.

Thank you

Comment: Did you load the file into a data.frame?

Comment: nope, but I will convert it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file is loaded into a data.frame named `df`, you can simply `sapply` `unique`:

```
sapply(df, unique)
```

This will give you a list where each element is a vector of all the alelles that have appeared in that column.